# Not able to add pointer to a vector in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

I am trying to implement a grid system to detect colission between tanks in a game.

My goal is to have around 40 cells which all have a vector with tank pointers. The tank should be in the right grid cell saved and updated whenever it moves to another.

When for the first time adding a tank pointer to a vector the application crashes. This is what my code looks like:

```
    vec2 position{ start_blue_x + ((i % max_rows) * spacing), start_blue_y + ((i / max_rows) * spacing) };
    Cell* tank_cell = Cell::find_cell_for_tank(position.x, position.y, cells);
    Tank tank = Tank(position.x, position.y, BLUE, tank_cell, &tank_blue, &smoke, 1100.f, position.y + 16, tank_radius, tank_max_health, tank_max_speed);
    tank_cell->tanks.push_back(&tank);
```

cell.h

```
Cell(int column, int row, vector<Tank*> tanks);
```

It seems to happen at the last line where I push the tank in the cell.

```
Exception thrown: Access violation reading
```

Cell::find_cell_for_tank()

```
    Cell* Cell::find_cell_for_tank(int pos_x, int pos_y, vector<Cell*>& cells)
{
    int tank_col = pos_x / CELL_WIDTH;
    int tank_row = pos_y / CELL_HEIGHT;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < cells.size(); i++) {
        if ((*cells.at(i)).column == tank_col && (*cells.at(i)).row == tank_row)
        {
            return cells.at(i);
        }
    }

    Cell* new_cell = &Cell(tank_col, tank_row, {});
    cells.push_back(new_cell);
    return new_cell;
}
```

Comment: First thing, have you checked whether `Cell::find_cell_for_tank` returns null?

Comment: If you get an exception on this line `tank_cell->tanks.push_back(&tank);` then the only real explanation is that `tank_cell` is a null or invalid pointer.

Comment: The other big red flag though is that you are pushing pointers to local objects onto your vectors, that's almost certainly a bug. Why have a vector of pointers to tanks? A vector of tanks is probably what you should be using.

Comment: Thanks for the fast comments guys. I updated the post with the find_cell_for_tank method. I am able to print tank_cell afterwards. So I do think it's present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bugged

```
Cell* new_cell = &Cell(tank_col, tank_row, {});
cells.push_back(new_cell);
return new_cell;
```

You are creating a temporary `Cell` object, pushing a pointer to the object onto a vector **and** returning a pointer to that temporary object.

The `Cell` object does not exist after the first line of code (it's a temporary), but those pointers to it still do. This is called a *dangling pointer*, and using either of those pointers is likely to crash your code.

Try not to use so many pointers. There is no reason for them, use `std::vector<Cell>` not `std::vector<Cell*>` and `std::vector<Tank>` not `std::vector<Tank*>`.

If you don't use pointers you cannot have dangling pointers.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense! Thanks for the clear explanation.

Comment: I already have a vector<Tank> tanks which saves all tanks. This would make it useful to have a vector <Tank*> tanks within the Cell object right? So I can always track the original tank back.

For the cells I will remove the pointer within the vector

Comment: @BasvanderVeen If you can be sure that the actual Tanks outlive the pointers to them then that is OK. **But** be careful of *vector reallocation*. If you add a tank to your vector then the vector may reallocate and that also will invalidate any existing pointers. If that is an issue then you should use indexes not pointers.